# Write to an XPages Dojo Filtering Select with CSJS

Tags: dojo, xpages, client-side

In an Xpage, on the CSJS onChange event, I am taking the value of a control (which is a Dojo Filtering Select) and setting the value of another Dojo Filtering Select control to the same value. Both controls use a @dbcolumn to create their lists of options.

```
var e = XSP.getElementById("#{id:DJFS1}").value;
XSP.getElementById("#{id:DJFS2}").value = e;
```

It works fine and changes the value of the 2nd control, except that it gives me "The entered value is not valid" error as it pops in there. 
If I use the arrow to select the value or use type ahead on that 2nd control, it works fine.
Any way I can get it to understand that the value I am writing to it is one of it's options and not give me the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dijit.byId()` to get to the Dojo Filtering Select - and then use `.set("value", value)` to set the value.

Here's an example (assuming that 0 is an alias for one of the possible values):

```
dijit.byId("#{id:DJFS1}").set("value", 0)
```

Comment: Great, Henrik. It worked. Just a follow up, and I think I'll have these filteringSelect boxes doing everything I want: I have a 3rd control DJFS3, and it's not tied to any other controls/fields on the xpage. All I am trying to do is highlight/select the entire value displayed/selected in that DJFS3 when I click in it (give it the focus).

Comment: I have a 3rd control DJFS3, and it's not tied to any other controls/fields on the xpage. All I am trying to do is highlight/select the entire value displayed/selected in that DJFS3 when I click in it (give it the focus).